# AWS cdk how to tag resources in TypeScript?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, aws-cdk

I have a cdk project in which I am creating an DynamoDB table and adding tag to it like below,

```
import * as core from "@aws-cdk/core";
import * as dynamodb from "@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb";
import { Tag } from "@aws-cdk/core";

export class DynamoDbTable extends core.Construct {
    constructor(scope: core.Construct, id: string) {
        super(scope, id);
        function addTags(resource : any) {
            Tag.add(resource, "Key", "value");
        }
        const table = new dynamodb.Table(this, "abcd", {
            partitionKey: { name: "name", type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING },
            stream: dynamodb.StreamViewType.NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES,
            tableName: 'tableName',
            billingMode: dynamodb.BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
        });
        addTags(table)
    }
}
```

Above code works fine add tags to table but this tagging method is deprecated now [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/java/deprecated-list.html) so how can I replace this tagging method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can tag a construct and CDK should add tags recursively. You shouldn't need to include your embedded `addTags` function. For example to use the newer non-deprecated method, in your code, you can use `this` to refer to the construct you are dealing with and do:

```
import { Tag } from "@aws-cdk/core";

export class DynamoDbTable extends core.Construct {
    constructor(scope: core.Construct, id: string) {
        super(scope, id);
        
        const table = new dynamodb.Table(this, "abcd", {
            partitionKey: { name: "name", type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING },
            stream: dynamodb.StreamViewType.NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES,
            tableName: 'tableName',
            billingMode: dynamodb.BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
        });

        Tags.of(this).add('Foo', 'Bar');
    }
}
```

Comment: DEPRECATED: add tags to the node of a construct and all its the taggable children.. This is what document says, so 'Tag.add(this, 'Foo', 'Bar');' wont work i guess.

Comment: ah yes sorry, missed that - I've updated to use an example of the new method.

Comment: Ok, in case if I have multiple resources to tag? will it be like, Tags.of(resource1Object).add('Foo', 'Bar').. Tags.of(resource2Object).add('Foo', 'Bar')

Comment: Yes as far as I'm aware, there is no method to add multiple tags at once. You could probably roll your own function that calls Tags.of 'n' times for each tag pair you feed it though (if that becomes tedious).